# php - associative array search is too slow

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The logic of my app is to get all data from the database in every request to API. The reason is the format of the data stored in database.

This is how I am storing data into associative array which works completely fine.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultAllBookings) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultAllBookings)){
            if(preg_match($bamsFormatRegex, $row['booking_name'])){
                $piecesOfBams     = explode('/', $row['booking_name']);
                $pdgName          = strtoupper($piecesOfBams[0]);
                $teamName         = strtoupper($piecesOfBams[3]);
                $deploymentNumber = $piecesOfBams[1];
                #~#
                if(!array_key_exists($pdgName, $selectBoxArray)){
                    $selectBoxArray[$pdgName] = Array();
                }
                if(!array_key_exists($teamName, $selectBoxArray[$pdgName])){
                    $selectBoxArray[$pdgName][$teamName] = Array();
                }
                array_push($selectBoxArray[$pdgName][$teamName], Array(
                    'name'  => $deploymentNumber,
                    'value' => $deploymentNumber,
                    'title' => $deploymentNumber,
                ));
                #~# 
                array_push($allBookingsData, array(
                    'booking_name'        => $row['booking_name'],
                    'asset_count'         => $row['booking_asset_count'],
                    'PDG'                 => $pdgName,
                    'Deployment_Number'   => $deploymentNumber,
                    'SPoC'                => $piecesOfBams[2],
                    'Team_Name'           => $teamName,
                    'Release'             => $piecesOfBams[4]                    
                ));       
            }else{

                $pdgName          = 'INVALID';
                $teamName         = 'INVALID';
                $deploymentNumber = 'INVALID';
                #~#
                if(!array_key_exists($pdgName, $selectBoxArray)){
                    $selectBoxArray[$pdgName] = Array();
                }
                if(!array_key_exists($teamName, $selectBoxArray[$pdgName])){
                    $selectBoxArray[$pdgName][$teamName] = Array();
                }
                array_push($selectBoxArray[$pdgName][$teamName], Array(
                    'name'  => $deploymentNumber,
                    'value' => $deploymentNumber,
                    'title' => $deploymentNumber,
                ));

                array_push($allBookingsData, array(
                    'booking_name'        => $row['booking_name'],
                    'asset_count'         => $row['booking_asset_count'],
                    'PDG'                 => 'INVALID',
                    'Deployment_Number'   => 'INVALID',
                    'SPoC'                => 'INVALID',
                    'Team_Name'           => 'INVALID',
                    'Release'             => 'INVALID'               
                ));
            }
        }
    }
```

Total 505 records into array. For GET request, `allBookingsData` array returned as it is and binds to the table on page. Works fine.

Now the issue is with POST request when user makes selection on a page.
Below is the example of one such field passed in POST request.

```
if($_POST){
        $tableData = Array();

            foreach ($allBookingsData as $key => $value) {
                if($value['PDG'] == $filterData['PDG']){
                    array_push($tableData, Array(
                        'booking_name'        => $value['booking_name'],
                        'asset_count'         => $value['asset_count'],
                        'PDG'                 => $value['PDG'],
                        'Deployment_Number'   => $value['Deployment_Number'],
                        'SPoC'                => $value['SPoC'],
                        'Team_Name'           => $value['Team_Name'],
                        'Release'             => $value['Release']               
                    ));
                }
            }               

    }else{
        $tableData = $allBookingsData;
    }
```

Here I am searching for records with specific PDG into `allBookingsData` array.
**Now this takes almost 12 seconds to finish the request and bind data to the page.**

It's only 505 records into the array. I couldn't figure out why searching into array takes this much of time.

**Update:**

Tried with `array_filter` but there is no change in response time. Still it takes 11-12 seconds to complete the request. And the server is not overloaded.

```
function searchByPDG($passedRecord){
    error_log('### searchByPDG ###');
    global $filterData;
    return ($passedRecord['PDG'] == $filterData['PDG']);
}

$tableData = array_filter($allBookingsData, "searchByPDG");
```

Sample record of `allBookingsData`:

```
[0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["booking_name"]=>
    string(39) "EITTE/91/EEIRCE/CORE NETWORK DESIGN/17B"
    ["asset_count"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["PDG"]=>
    string(5) "EITTE"
    ["Deployment_Number"]=>
    string(2) "91"
    ["SPoC"]=>
    string(6) "EEIRCE"
    ["Team_Name"]=>
    string(19) "CORE NETWORK DESIGN"
    ["Release"]=>
    string(3) "17B"
  }
```

**Update-2:**

I checked execution time of first and second block of code as given here. And it's respectively  1.0050439834595 and  1.0006971359253 microseconds. But it takes 11-12 seconds to return and bind the data. I've attached screenshot of developer tools.

[image]

**How do I optimize this code ?**

Comment: What is `$allBookingsData` and how does it get populated?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑThe first codebox is populating his array

Comment: try to use array_filter http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: @DarkBee I don't even know how I didn't see that code block `:(` - Thanks

Comment: I have no idea why PHP is so slow here, shouldn't be. But I think you should filter data in database. There is no need for DB to send all rows to php. You can filter it with SUBSTRING_INDEX function. select * from xyz where SUBSTRING_INDEX(booking_name,'/',1) = 'EITTE'; or something like that

Comment: How do you measure the time? There's no way looping on 500 records can take 12 seconds. Isn't it the database that is slow to respond? Or maybe it's a query on a very large table?

Comment: @this.lau_ yes you are right. I checked execution time of first and second block of code as given here. And it's respectively  1.0050439834595 and  1.0006971359253 microseconds. But it takes 11-12 seconds to return and bind the data. I've attached screenshot of developer tools.

Comment: Issue resolved. It was my mistake. I missed where clause query variable in case of POST and I haven't put that query part here in question. And as query was missing where clause, it took 12 seconds due to left join in it. Thanks everyone.